# How to access TextView on top of a View

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am trying a simple application where I wanted to show some values within a circle. I referred some article and using `shape` files I can able to generate circle. 
But I am not able to add `TextView` within that circle.
Can anyone help me in solving this?

here is my `shape` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke  android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

here is my layout file.

```
//<RelaiveLayout> outer RelativeLayout
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eDeleted"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
          <View android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a `TextView` within `View`.

Comment: Use textview instead of view and add @drawable/circle as the textview's background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:gravity="center"/>
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

`View` cannot contain child views, only `ViewGroup` can do that. `LinearLayout` is a `ViewGroup`, so, you can replace your `View` with a `TextView` and try setting a background on your layout or text view itself.